# postgres запрос выполняется долго

Tags: c++, sql, qt, postgresql

Хочу сделать полнотекстовый поиск на postgres. Создавал индекс gin-

```
CREATE INDEX "Table_idx"
ON "Table"
USING gin
(to_tsvector('russian_hunspell'::regconfig, "TextOfFile"::text));)
```

Такой запрос

```
SELECT "ID", "FileName"
FROM "Table"
WHERE to_tsvector('russian_hunspell', "TextOfFile") @@ to_tsquery ('russian_hunspell', 'Книга')
```

выполняется 23 секунды, пробовал создать индекс -

```
CREATE INDEX ON "Table"("TextOfFile");
```

выводит ошибку-

```
ОШИБКА: строка индекса требует байт: 4926200, при максимуме: 8191
********** Ошибка **********

ОШИБКА: строка индекса требует байт: 4926200, при максимуме: 8191
SQL-состояние: 54000
```

Сама идея - в базе есть таблица с 3 колонками: ID, FileName, TextOfFile.
Я добавляю разные файлы (размером от 1 кб до 15 мб)
через прогу на qt, и внутрь TextOfFile записывается содержимое файла
(одна строчка, в ней одна ячейка- это один файл).
Если заносить файлы размером свыше 10 мб,
то gin долго ищет по ним(23 сек),
если попробовать использовать другой индекс, например IndexOnlyScan вместо Req Scan, то при
создании индекса, выводить ошибка. (Немного читал про TOAST, особо идей нет.
Подскажите как грамотно занести большой
текст в ячейку, чтобы потом можно было быстро (1-2 сек) искать в нем что-либо
(Пока занес в таблицу 35 строк, это 35 файлов, 34 файла меньше 2 кб и один 12 мб).

Comment: и вот на точно таком же вопросе я 100 лет назад ушёл на sphinx

Comment: Может быть есть идеи как это вообще можно решить?

Comment: А план выполнения смотрели, индекс вообще используется ? если индекс есть это еще не значит что он будет использован. Например при создании индекса используется приведение типов вроде ::text, а в запросе нет. Это вполне может смутить оптимизатор и он решит что использовать индекс нельзя. Что до второго индекса который вы пытаетесь создавать - так он вообще не предназначен для полнотекстового поиска, а только на вхождение и только с самого начала строки. И он логично не создается, потому что нет смысла индексировать такие объемы таким индексом

Comment: И вот тут https://habr.com/ru/post/442170/ рекомендуют сделать колонку tsvector в БД, она конечно займет много места, но куда деваться. Наличие колонки дает большой рост производительности